# SQL SERVER Duplicated Row Data in Subquery

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract the result of a person in a poll by type of poll and a determined year, group by area.

This is the tables scripts and some sample data:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ANSWERS]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ANSWERS](
    [FK_QUESTION] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CHOICE] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TYPE_POLL] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FK_ID_PERSON] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ANSWERS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FK_QUESTION] ASC,
    [TYPE_POLL] ASC,
    [FK_ID_PERSON] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AREA]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AREA](
    [ID_AREA] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_POLL] [int] NULL,
    [NAME_AREA] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AREA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_AREA] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[JOBS]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JOBS](
    [ID_JOB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME_JOB] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_srh3100t] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_JOB] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PERSON]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PERSON](
    [ID_PERSON] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [JOB_PERSON] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [LAST_NAME] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PERSON] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_PERSON] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[POINTS]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POINTS](
    [FK_JOB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_QUESTION] [int] NOT NULL,
    [POINT] [numeric](4, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_POINTS_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FK_JOB] ASC,
    [FK_QUESTION] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[POLL]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POLL](
    [ID_POLL] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [YEARS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_BEG] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DATE_END] [date] NOT NULL,
    [AUTO] [numeric](4, 2) NOT NULL,
    [BOSS] [numeric](4, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_POLL_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_POLL] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[QUESTION]    Script Date: 09/09/2015 7:08:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QUESTION](
    [ID_QUESTION] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_AREA] [int] NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](400) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QUESTION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_QUESTION] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ANSWERS] ([FK_QUESTION], [CHOICE], [TYPE_POLL], [FK_ID_PERSON]) VALUES (1, 1, 0, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[ANSWERS] ([FK_QUESTION], [CHOICE], [TYPE_POLL], [FK_ID_PERSON]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[ANSWERS] ([FK_QUESTION], [CHOICE], [TYPE_POLL], [FK_ID_PERSON]) VALUES (2, 1, 0, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[ANSWERS] ([FK_QUESTION], [CHOICE], [TYPE_POLL], [FK_ID_PERSON]) VALUES (2, 2, 1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[ANSWERS] ([FK_QUESTION], [CHOICE], [TYPE_POLL], [FK_ID_PERSON]) VALUES (3, 3, 0, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[ANSWERS] ([FK_QUESTION], [CHOICE], [TYPE_POLL], [FK_ID_PERSON]) VALUES (3, 1, 1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AREA] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[AREA] ([ID_AREA], [FK_POLL], [NAME_AREA]) VALUES (1, 1, N'AREA 1')
INSERT [dbo].[AREA] ([ID_AREA], [FK_POLL], [NAME_AREA]) VALUES (2, 1, N'AREA 2')
INSERT [dbo].[AREA] ([ID_AREA], [FK_POLL], [NAME_AREA]) VALUES (3, 1, N'AREA 3')
INSERT [dbo].[AREA] ([ID_AREA], [FK_POLL], [NAME_AREA]) VALUES (4, 1, N'AREA 4')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AREA] OFF
INSERT [dbo].[JOBS] ([ID_JOB], [NAME_JOB]) VALUES (1, N'JOB 1')
INSERT [dbo].[JOBS] ([ID_JOB], [NAME_JOB]) VALUES (2, N'JOB 2')
INSERT [dbo].[JOBS] ([ID_JOB], [NAME_JOB]) VALUES (3, N'JOB  3')
INSERT [dbo].[JOBS] ([ID_JOB], [NAME_JOB]) VALUES (4, N'JOB 4')
INSERT [dbo].[PERSON] ([ID_PERSON], [JOB_PERSON], [NAME], [LAST_NAME]) VALUES (CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 1, N'MATT', N'TUCK')
INSERT [dbo].[PERSON] ([ID_PERSON], [JOB_PERSON], [NAME], [LAST_NAME]) VALUES (CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 2, N'MATT', N'HEAFY')
INSERT [dbo].[PERSON] ([ID_PERSON], [JOB_PERSON], [NAME], [LAST_NAME]) VALUES (CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 3, N'SYNISTER', N'GATES')
INSERT [dbo].[PERSON] ([ID_PERSON], [JOB_PERSON], [NAME], [LAST_NAME]) VALUES (CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 4, N'THOMAS', N'YOUNGBLOOD')
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (1, 2, CAST(2.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (1, 3, CAST(3.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (1, 4, CAST(4.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(1.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(2.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (2, 3, CAST(3.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[POINTS] ([FK_JOB], [FK_QUESTION], [POINT]) VALUES (2, 4, CAST(4.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[POLL] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[POLL] ([ID_POLL], [YEARS], [NAME], [DATE_BEG], [DATE_END], [AUTO], [BOSS]) VALUES (1, 2015, N'POLL 1', CAST(0x693A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD23A0B00 AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)), CAST(80.00 AS Numeric(4, 2)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[POLL] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (1, 1, N'QUESTION 1', N'aaa')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (2, 1, N'QUESTION 2', N'bbb')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (3, 2, N'QUESTION 3', N'ccc')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (4, 2, N'QUESTION 4', N'ddd')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (5, 3, N'QUESTION 5', N'eee')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (6, 3, N'QUESTION 6', N'fff')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (7, 4, N'QUESTION 7', N'ggg')
INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] ([ID_QUESTION], [FK_AREA], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION]) VALUES (8, 4, N'QUESTION 8', N'hhh')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[QUESTION] OFF
USE [master]
GO
```

And this is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT AREA.NAME_AREA,
  (SELECT SUM(ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5) WHERE ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL= 0) AS RESULT_PERSON,
  (SELECT SUM(ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5) WHERE ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL= 1) AS RESULT_BOSS
  FROM  POLL INNER JOIN
                         AREA ON POLL.ID_POLL = AREA.FK_POLL INNER JOIN
                         QUESTION ON AREA.ID_AREA = QUESTION.FK_AREA INNER JOIN
                         POINTS ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = POINTS.FK_QUESTION INNER JOIN
                         JOBS INNER JOIN
                         PERSON ON JOBS.ID_JOB = PERSON.JOB_PERSON ON POINTS.FK_JOB = JOBS.ID_JOB INNER JOIN
                         ANSWERS ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = ANSWERS.FK_QUESTION AND PERSON.ID_PERSON = ANSWERS.FK_ID_PERSON
WHERE        (POLL.YEARS = 2015) AND (PERSON.ID_PERSON = 1) GROUP BY AREA.NAME_AREA , ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL
```

And I want the output be like this:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| NAME_AREA  | RESULT_PERSON | RESULT_BOSS   |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| AREA 1     |           0.6 |     1         |
| AREA 2     |           1.8 |     0.6       |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

But I'm getting the result like this:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| NAME_AREA  | RESULT_PERSON | RESULT_BOSS   |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| AREA 1     |           0.6 |     NULL      |
| AREA 2     |           1.8 |     NULL      |
| AREA 1     |        NULL   |             1 |
| AREA 2     |        NULL   |           0.6 |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

It is something I am missing...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reading your query and finding better solution:

```
SELECT  t.NAME_AREA, MAX(t.RESULT_PERSON) AS RESULT_PERSON, MAX(t.RESULT_BOSS) AS RESULT_BOSS
FROM (
SELECT AREA.NAME_AREA,
  (SELECT SUM(ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5) WHERE ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL= 0) AS RESULT_PERSON,
  (SELECT SUM(ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5) WHERE ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL= 1) AS RESULT_BOSS
  FROM  POLL INNER JOIN
                         AREA ON POLL.ID_POLL = AREA.FK_POLL INNER JOIN
                         QUESTION ON AREA.ID_AREA = QUESTION.FK_AREA INNER JOIN
                         POINTS ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = POINTS.FK_QUESTION INNER JOIN
                         JOBS INNER JOIN
                         PERSON ON JOBS.ID_JOB = PERSON.JOB_PERSON ON POINTS.FK_JOB = JOBS.ID_JOB INNER JOIN
                         ANSWERS ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = ANSWERS.FK_QUESTION AND PERSON.ID_PERSON = ANSWERS.FK_ID_PERSON
WHERE        (POLL.YEARS = 2015) AND (PERSON.ID_PERSON = 1) GROUP BY AREA.NAME_AREA , ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL)
AS t
GROUP BY NAME_AREA;
```

I am aware there are more efficient and secure ways, this is just quick workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass It to subquery and add only `NAME_AREA` to `GROUP BY` clause in following:

```
SELECT NAME_AREA, MAX(RESULT_PERSON) AS RESULT_PERSON, MAX(RESULT_BOSS) AS RESULT_BOSS
FROM(
    SELECT AREA.NAME_AREA,
      (SELECT SUM(ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5) WHERE ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL= 0) AS RESULT_PERSON,
      (SELECT SUM(ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5) WHERE ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL= 1) AS RESULT_BOSS
    FROM  POLL INNER JOIN
                             AREA ON POLL.ID_POLL = AREA.FK_POLL INNER JOIN
                             QUESTION ON AREA.ID_AREA = QUESTION.FK_AREA INNER JOIN
                             POINTS ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = POINTS.FK_QUESTION INNER JOIN
                             JOBS INNER JOIN
                             PERSON ON JOBS.ID_JOB = PERSON.JOB_PERSON ON POINTS.FK_JOB = JOBS.ID_JOB INNER JOIN
                             ANSWERS ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = ANSWERS.FK_QUESTION AND PERSON.ID_PERSON = ANSWERS.FK_ID_PERSON
    WHERE        (POLL.YEARS = 2015) AND (PERSON.ID_PERSON = 1) 
    GROUP BY AREA.NAME_AREA , ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL
)x
GROUP BY NAME_AREA
```

**OUTPUT**

```
NAME_AREA   RESULT_PERSON   RESULT_BOSS
AREA 1      0.600000        1.000000
AREA 2      1.800000        0.600000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT AREA.NAME_AREA,
       Sum(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL = 0 THEN ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5 ELSE 0 END) AS RESULT_PERSON,
       Sum(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.TYPE_POLL = 1 THEN ANSWERS.CHOICE * POINTS.POINT / 5 ELSE 0 END) AS RESULT_BOSS
FROM   POLL
       INNER JOIN AREA
               ON POLL.ID_POLL = AREA.FK_POLL
       INNER JOIN QUESTION
               ON AREA.ID_AREA = QUESTION.FK_AREA
       INNER JOIN POINTS
               ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = POINTS.FK_QUESTION
       INNER JOIN JOBS
               ON POINTS.FK_JOB = JOBS.ID_JOB
       INNER JOIN PERSON
               ON JOBS.ID_JOB = PERSON.JOB_PERSON
       INNER JOIN ANSWERS
               ON QUESTION.ID_QUESTION = ANSWERS.FK_QUESTION
                  AND PERSON.ID_PERSON = ANSWERS.FK_ID_PERSON
WHERE  ( POLL.YEARS = 2015 )
       AND ( PERSON.ID_PERSON = 1 )
GROUP  BY AREA.NAME_AREA
```